# Window.open alternative

Tags: javascript, browser, controls

I want to open the browser in background using window.open
But that new browser should not be visible
Or please suggest any alternative of window.open

Any help would be appericiate.

Comment: Please share the code you have used to open the window.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "that new browser should not be visible"? Do you literally mean an invisible window? Or just hidden behind the existing window (a so-called "pop-under")? If the latter: Browsers are very good at preventing pop-unders these days, since they've been used for malicious purposes so often.

Answer (score 0):

> But that new browser should not be visible

You can't do that with browser-based JavaScript (or HTML, for that matter).

You **can** have a zero-height `iframe` in the window your code is already running in. I've done that when I needed a target for a form that results in a downloadable file: I target the zero-height `iframe` and when the response comes back, the user is prompted to save it somewhere. (I do that instead of using a new blank window to avoid having a window pop-up that the user isn't going to use for anything, esp. since the window didn't go away in IE at the time I did this.)

---

If by "not be visible" you just mean it should be hidden behind the existing window (a so-called "pop-under"): Browsers are very good at preventing pop-unders these days, since they've been used for malicious purposes so often.

Comment: I think the questioner wants the new window not to be focused, when new window is opened.

Comment: @JennisVaishnav - That is one possible interpretation of "should not be visible" I suppose. :-) I took the more literal interpretation.

Comment: Actually my requirement is,  In my website i have integrated third party website API. SO when i will login in my website it should be automatic login in that party website as well l. for that auto login i have used window.open and pass the third party website url

Comment: @T.j Crowder using the iframe is not possible because that third party have CROS enable

Comment: @HemantNaringhani - `iframe`s can be cross-origin, you just can't *talk* to them. What is "CROS"? Do you mean CORS? (Them having CORS enabled for your origin would actually be a *good* thing for you in terms of doing this.)

Comment: Oh yeah, i am sorry Its CORS

Comment: @T.j Crowder i have tried with Ifame as well but j am getting error for CORS

Comment: @HemantNaringhani - Again, them having CORS enabled for your origin would be a *good thing* for you. You mean they **don't** have CORS enabled, so the default Same Origin Policy is preventing your doing what you're doing cross-origin. Using a window rather than an `iframe` won't make that any better. It sounds like they don't want people doing what you're trying to do.